# Locking aspect ratio causes flickering of the window

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, aspect-ratio, window-resize

I am working on an application witch requires me to force the main window to have a locked aspect ratio. I found this snippet [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150330022650/http://bobpowell.net/controlaspect.aspx). It works, but the window flickers while being re-sized.

```
float _currentRatio;
bool _lockRatio=false;

public bool LockRatio
{
    get{ return _lockRatio; }
    set{ _lockRatio=value; }
}

protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if(!_lockRatio)
        this._currentRatio=(float)this.Height/(float)this.Width;
    else
        this.Height=(int)(this.Width*this._currentRatio);

    base.OnSizeChanged (e);
}
```

Is there any way of avoiding that flicker?

Comment: Try [this link](http://www.vcskicks.com/maintain-aspect-ratio.php). Basically, use the `WndProc` and not the .NET events (which ocurr AFTER the size is changed)

Comment: write that as answer, for me to accept it, because it works perfectly!